# VB.net entry with same primary key duplicates when updating

Tags: vb.net

I have an entry with a primary key field but needs to update other fields. However, when I update the fields my grid does not save my update, or nothing happens..  can someone help me please.

thanks

Comment: Please, provide a sample of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to pass primary key to the update parameter when updating the records.
removed it from update set parameters.. retry after removing..

for example:

```
Update Table_Name set name=@name where primary_ID = @primary_ID
```